# Vuejs - When should jquery plugins be initialised

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I have some JQuery plugins that need initialising, normally this could be done using `$(document).ready(function () { })` but this doesn't appear to work when doing it within a vue components `created` event. With this in mind, I've made use of `this.$nextTick(function () { })` but this doesn't seem to work with elements that are introduced on child component. For instance, I do this:

```
created: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    window.materialadmin.AppOffcanvas.initialize()
  })
}
```

I have a button which is introduced in a child component but the onclick handler this above code attaches doesn't trigger. If I do:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    window.materialadmin.AppOffcanvas.initialize()
}, 1000)
```

Then my click handler will be bound and work.

At what point is the correct point to bind my events so that I don't need to rely on `setTimeout` which is hacky?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mounted](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) or [updated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) [Lifecycle-Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks) should solve your problem as mounted is called after the instance has just been mounted where el is replaced by the newly created vm.$el and updated is called after a data change causes the virtual DOM to be re-rendered and patched.